# Bigcommerce stencil 'theme_settings' not available during ajax request in production

Tags: bigcommerce

I have some custom shipping method names defined in my `config.json` like this:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "shipping_methods": {
            "Free Shipping": {
                "display_name": "Free Shipping",
                "transit_time": "2-5 Business Days"
            },
            "UPS Ground and 3 Day Select (Ground)": {
                "display_name": "UPS Ground",
                "transit_time": "1-5 Business Days"
            },
            "UPS Ground and 3 Day Select (3 Day Select)": {
                "display_name": "UPS 3 Day Select",
                "transit_time": "3 Business Days"
            },
            "UPS 2nd Day Air and Next Day (2nd Day Air)": {
                "display_name": "UPS 2nd Day Air",
                "transit_time": "2 Business Days"
            },
            "UPS 2nd Day Air and Next Day (Next Day Air)": {
                "display_name": "UPS Next Day Air",
                "transit_time": "Next Business Day"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my `templates/components/cart/shipping-quotes.html` file, I loop through these shipping methods in order to adjust the shipping methods returned by the system, like this:

```
<form>
    {{#if quotes.shipping_methods}}
      <table class="shippingEstimator-list">
        <tbody>
        {{#each quotes.shipping_methods}}
          {{#with (lookup ../theme_settings.shipping_methods provider_name)}}
            <tr class="shippingEstimator-item">
              <td class="shippingEstimator-method">
                <div class="shippingEstimator-name">
                  {{display_name}}
                </div>
                <div class="shippingEstimator-time">
                  {{transit_time}}
                </div>
              </td>
              <td class="shippingEstimator-price">
                {{../cost.formatted}}
              </td>
              <td class="shippingEstimator-select">
                <button class="button primary hollow expanded" data-select-shipping-quote="{{../id}}">Select</button>
              </td>
            </tr>
            {{/with}}
          {{/each}}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    {{/if}}
  </form>
```

This works perfectly in development. However, when I upload the theme to a live store, my shipping quotes were always turning up blank.

After investigating this, I found that in the live store, the `theme_settings` object is not present in the context when the store makes the ajax call to retrieve shipping quotes.

Why is the `theme_settings` object not available to an ajax request in production? This seems like a rather serious bug.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added entries for these settings objects in your schema.json file?  Entries in your config.json file are only exposed to the theme editor if they are mapped in your theme's schema.json file.

Take a look at the relevant documentation [here](https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/schemajson-metadata-for-theme-editor)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but this does not have anything to do with theme editor. This is a custom stencil theme for one specific client. Theme editor is not usable for any part of this. These entries in config.json are specifically there to provide a mapping of data for the handlebars files to refer to. It works as expected in development, but the `theme_settings` are missing in production. It's definitely a bug in the platform. Just hoping someone gets back to me soon to confirm...

Comment: Hey there, I probably should have elaborated a bit more in my answer.  The setting object needs to get defined in the schema.json file whether you intend you use the theme editor or not.  Defining the theme setting in schema.json triggers BC's server to include the relevant setting data in a 'stencil-config' header when requested by your theme.  Everything works in the local theme emulator, because the local hapi server just assumes that header data will be present on the live server if it can't find the appropriate theme setting in front matter....more info follows...

Comment: Have a look at the relevant code inside the development server here, starting around line 270: https://github.com/bigcommerce/stencil-cli/blob/dcbe032dda70b8f6ae0873ca7636a5faf30b737d/server/plugins/renderer/renderer.module.js.  The live server apparently scans the theme's schema.json to determine what data to drop in to the 'stencil-config' header.  I encountered this on a recent client project for custom settings objects that I wasn't trying to expose to the theme editor...only after digging through the stencil-cli source did I edit schema.json, and all worked as intended. Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh wow, very interesting. Thank you very much for elaborating. How exactly would this data get entered into schema.json though? I'm not seeing how config.json and schema.json connect?

Comment: I'm also not really following why it would behave differently in production than it does in development. That still seems like a bug to me.

Comment: The data doesn't get entered in the schema file...you've already got the data set properly in your config.json.  You just need to define the field in the schema.json file, which clues BC's live server (& theme editor) in that your settings fields exist.  I'm on my cell don't have access to an example...but take a look at schema.json in the Cornerstone theme...should be pretty easy to see how it matches up with the stock config file.  I think this isn't so much a bug as it is a case of BC doing something proprietary behind the scenes regarding those 'stencil-config' headers that we can't see

Comment: With that said, I'd agree that it's definitely a bug that stencil-cli doesn't throw up some kind of a warning or error message.  The documentation doesn't touch on this at all either...it was a fair amount of blood sweat and tears for me to figure this out the first time!

Comment: Bigcommerce confirmed this was a bug and have now fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be better to just provide that meta data in the YAML markup on the shipping-quotes.html file?

From my understanding, the config.json and schema.json files are unnecessary here because we aren't trying to add this into the theme settings box.

On a side note, I would probably lean more towards having this injected with javascript and having the javascript file hosted via the webdav where you can access it more easily. I cant imagine having to re-upload the theme every time you want to make a wording change or your transit time's shift.

```
<!-- templates/components/cart/shipping-quotes.html -->

---
shipping_methods_meta:
    "Free Shipping": 
        - display_name: "Free Shipping"
          transit_time: "2-5 Business Days"
    "UPS Ground and 3 Day Select (Ground)":
        - display_name: "UPS Ground"
          transit_time: "1-5 Business Days"
    "UPS Ground and 3 Day Select (3 Day Select)":
        - display_name: "UPS 3 Day Select"
          transit_time: "2 Business Days"
---

<form>
{{#if quotes.shipping_methods}}
    <table class="shippingEstimator-list">
        <tbody>
            {{#each quotes.shipping_methods}}
            {{#with (lookup shipping_methods_meta provider_name)}}
            <tr class="shippingEstimator-item">
                <td class="shippingEstimator-method">
                    <div class="shippingEstimator-name">
                        {{display_name}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="shippingEstimator-time">
                        {{transit_time}}
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="shippingEstimator-price">
                    {{../cost.formatted}}
                </td>
                <td class="shippingEstimator-select">
                    <button class="button primary hollow expanded" data-select-shipping-quote="{{../id}}">Select</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            {{/with}}
            {{/each}}
        </tbody>
    </table>
{{/if}}
</form>
```